# Rewrite URL so that utm_expid is hidden

Tags: url-rewriting

I'm running A/B tests using google analytics.

I am trying to rewrite URL so that utm_expid is hidden.

When I visit my URL which is something like `www.website.com`, it is redirected to 
`http://www.website.com/?utm_expid=67183125-2`

how would i remove the `utm...`, so the user only sees `www.website.com`?

Comment: Kindly check your .htaccess file there the default path of website will be defined

Comment: Hi, Can you explain more please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a search and replace filter, as documented here: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034834?hl=en.

Here is an example:

[image]

Note that S&R filters only apply to data going forward, not on historical data.